# Servlet Issue - Index page not popping up

Tags: java, servlets

I am using spring framework and i am having `Index.jsp` like :

Code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>File Upload</p>
    <form action="ImportService" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="file1"><br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Upload File"><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

I have `ImportService` as

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class ImportService extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = "c:\\tmp";
    private File tmpDir;
    private static final String DESTINATION_DIR_PATH = "c:\\files";
    private File destinationDir;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        tmpDir = new File(TMP_DIR_PATH);
        if (!tmpDir.isDirectory()) {
            throw new ServletException(TMP_DIR_PATH + " is not a directory");
        }
        // String realPath =
        // getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH);
        destinationDir = new File(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH);
        if (!destinationDir.isDirectory()) {
            throw new ServletException(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH
                    + " is not a directory");
        }

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = "param";
        String value = request.getParameter(name);

        String welcomeMessage = "Welcome " + value;
        System.out.println("Message=" + welcomeMessage);

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        System.out.println("Inside Get Method");

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside Post Method");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        /*
         * Set the size threshold, above which content will be stored on disk.
         */
        fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1 * 1024 * 1024); // 1 MB

        /*
         * Set the temporary directory to store the uploaded files of size above
         * threshold.
         */
        fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);

        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
        try {
            /*
             * Parse the request
             */
            List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator itr = items.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
                /*
                 * Handle Form Fields.
                 */
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    out.println("File Name = " + item.getFieldName()
                            + ", Value = " + item.getString());
                } else {
                    // Handle Uploaded files.
                    out.println("Field Name = " + item.getFieldName()
                            + ", File Name = " + item.getName()
                            + ", Content type = " + item.getContentType()
                            + ", File Size = " + item.getSize());

                }

                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            log("Error encountered while parsing the request", ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log("Error encountered while uploading file", ex);
        }
        // doGet(request, response);

    }
}
```

In my web.xml, I have

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ImportService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.service.ImportService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ImportService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ImportService/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Now when I try to hit the url: http://localhost:8080/delta-webapp/ImportService/jsp/Index.jsp then it gives me blank message and html form is not rendered.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: have you defined a Servlet mapping? (see here, i.e. http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/servlet/tutorial/helloworld/index.xtp). Plus: your JSP won't be located after the servlet path, but just after the context-path

Comment: yes, i do have that mapping in there

Comment: So your servlet responds to every URL that matches http://localhost:8080/delta-webapp/ImportService/*, still your JSP will be located under http://localhost:8080/delta-webapp/jsp/Index.jsp Can you access it there? Your JSP file and your Servlet are not related, except the form in the jsp sends its form data to the servlet later...

Comment: No, i am not able to access jsp at  localhost:8080/delta-webapp/jsp/Index.jsp, it gives me 404 message

Comment: any suggestions or approaches?

Comment: check if your app has been successfully deployed in tomcat manager, also check the logfiles for possible exceptions upon startup. try to set up a simple webapp without spring and possible other frameworks to see where your error comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your entry URL from http://localhost:8080/delta-webapp/ImportService/jsp/Index.jsp
to http://localhost:8080/delta-webapp/jsp/Index.jsp

You've mapped ImportService servlet to handle all requests to /ImportService/*.

Your index.jsp is located at /jsp/Index.jsp.  If instead you just put /delta-webapp It /may/ work.

In general though, I don't think welcome files have hard coded paths.  Typically you specify something like index.jsp as your welcome file and if nothing handles the request at a particular location, it will fall back to see if one of the welcome files listed is available and will render that.

Comment: am getting 404 error, when i try to hit http://localhost:8080/delta-webapp/jsp/Index.jsp

Comment: did you store your jsp in a folder called "jsp" in your webapp?

Comment: @Rachel which container are you running? tomcat? Secondly, how are you deploying your application?

Comment: tc server, add and remove resource to deploy application

Comment: Ok if you are using the TC manager, (which I'm assuming you are based on above comments), I would deploy the application then check the work directory where the application is actually unpacked.  Verify that your JSP file is in fact located where you are saying it is.

Comment: I got it fixed, actually i had to place index.jsp in delta-webapp/index.jsp and i was able to retrieve it

Comment: I was beginning to suspect that. Ok so the &lt;welcome-file&gt; is a file that is relative (most likely within) a requested location where no other handler has been found. I am unsure if there are restrictions with regard to the path or the depth allowed in that element but the servlet specification should be able to point you in the right direction with regard to that. Glad you got it figured out.